# React.JS: Reset hook before call a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form that I use as search filter. In this Search Filter I have a reset button that should delete the choose done.

So in my form if the button is clicked i call the `handleFormReset`

```
export const MyPage = (props) => {
  const [realmFilter, setRealmFilter] = useState(null);

  const sortEntities = () => {
    const search = realmFilter !== null ? realmFilter : anotherVariable
    // api call using search
  }

  const handleFormReset = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setRealmFilter(null);
    sortEntities();
    }

//

return(

  //....
        <AvForm model={formModel} onSubmit={filterResults} onReset={handleFormReset}>


}
```

In my sortEntities I check if realmFilter variable is null and take another value to make an api call.

The problem is that when I click the reset button the setRealmFilter don't set on null, so I call the sortEntities but the realmFilter has the same value of before. If I click another time on reset it works.

So the workflow is:

> Set a realmFilter --> call sortEntities -> it makes api call (it works)

> Press on reset button -> call handleFormReset -> realmFilter is not set on null ->
> call sortEntities -> realmFilter is not null so I use this value (
> wrong because it should be null)

> Press another time reset button -> call handleFormReset -> realmFilter is set on null

How can I do to set to null realmFilter when reset button is clicked?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A state change is not done immediately, by this I mean that `setRealmFilter` is not gonna change `realmFilter` in this task.

Your function `sortEntities` is gonna get called right after the end of `setRealmFilter` and will get a `staled` value.

You have 2 choices here:

1. Use `useEffect` and use `realmFilter` as a dep.
2. Just move the function inside the handler and call it there.

Most likely you want the second approach.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't understand when you say to move inside handler, at the moment I have insert inside handler. How you suggest to do?